# How can I remove my slash URLs with an .htaccess from localhost XAMPP

Tags: php, .htaccess, slash

**For example:**

```
<a href="/example/">example</a>
```

**to**

```
<a href="example">example</a>
```

**or**

`<link type="text/css" href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`

**to**

`<link type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d18XB.png)

**my htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Please help!....

Answer (score 0):

**What about this?**

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$/ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$/ $1/ [R=301,L]